# Firebase Function, Firestore, & Axios - Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, axios

Using a Firebase Function with Axios. Just trying to iterate over a response object of objects and store each child object as a Firestore Doc inside a collection.

The logs show the following error:

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
>
> at Object.validateDocumentData (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:576:15)
> at CollectionReference.add (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1964:23)
> at /workspace/index.js:35:18
> at Array.map ()
> at /workspace/index.js:34:14
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Here's the code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 2 minutes")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await
        db.collection("my_collection").get();
        const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          db.collection("my_collection").doc(doc.id).delete());

        await Promise.all(promises);

        const Options = {
          method: "get",
          url: "...",
          headers: {
            "Cookie": "...",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };

        const axiosResponse = await axios(Options);
        const axiosData = axiosResponse.data;
        const parsedAxiosResponse = axiosData["news_results"];

        const documentCreationPromises = parsedResponse
            .map(() => db.collection("my_collection")
                .add(parsedAxiosResponse));

        await Promise.all(documentCreationPromises);

        return null;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(parsedResponse)` and share the output?

Comment: `parsedResponse` is never declared nor initialized in the code you shared, which means you should be getting an error on `parsedResponse.map(...)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - that was an unrelated type on my part. Fixed above now.

Comment: So what is `parsedAxiosResponse`? If it's a string (json / html / xml, ...) instead of a Javascript Object (parsed JSON), obviously it can't be stored to Firestore as a document.  And there's still no `parsedResponse` defined anywhere even though you are mapping it like it should be an array.

Comment: console.log of parsedAxiosResponse shows [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc. I thought I might need to parse it. When I do axiosData = JSON.partse(axiosResponse.data) I get an error message of `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. My noob understanding of Axios is that it auto-parses the data for you, returning a JS object by default. So I shouldn't need to json.parse, right?

Comment: @Dharmaraj - array of objects. Just to rule out any issues with .map.

Comment: @thebenCA we'll probably need output of  `JSON.stringify(axiosResponse.data)` tbh. Just paste it here then we'll use some JSON formatter to check it

Comment: Much appreciated everyone. 

JSON.stringify(axiosResponse.date) ===

`{"title":"Auto racing: Sheppard holds off Madden to win a World of ...","link":"https://www.pinejournal.com/sports/motorsports/7106296-Auto-racing-Sheppard-holds-off-Madden-to-win-a-World-of-Outlaws-Late-Model-thriller-in-Superior","date":"3 weeks ago","source":"Pine Journal","description":"An estimated 2,500 fans were in attendance for the World of Outlaws Late \nModels Series stop at Gondik Law Speedway in Superior, and Brandon ...","thumbnail":"data:..."}`

Comment: What's 'parsedAutoRacingResponse' ?

Comment: There is no `news_results` property in the output you have shared... i.e. `axiosResponse.data.news_results` is `undefined`

Comment: @Dharmaraj - sorry, you can disregard that. I had that added earlier as part of my console.log and forgot to delete it. I fixed it above.

Comment: Okay but `axiosResponse.data` is an object... are you trying to upload that in Firestore? Copy that in https://jsonformatter.org/ for better view.

Comment: @Dharmaraj - yes, I would like to store each returned object as its own document inside a Firestore collection.

{"title":"Auto racing: Sheppard holds off Madden to win a World of ...",
"link":"https://www.pinejournal.com/sports.com",
"date":"3 weeks ago","source":"Pine Journal",
"description": "Big event results in unexpected winner",
"date_parsed":"2021-07-13T17:57:09+00:00"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235594/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-thebenca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsedAxiosResponse` seems to be an array and you are trying set that array itself to all the new Firestore documents instead of the elements in that array.

```js
const colRef = db.collection("my_collection")

const parsedAxiosResponse = axiosData["news_results"];

const documentCreationPromises = parsedResponse.map(() => colRef.add(parsedAxiosResponse));
                                                                     ^^^^^
```

As you need to create a new document for each object in that array, try this:

```js
const parsedAxiosResponse = axiosData["news_results"];

const documentCreationPromises = parsedResponse.map((element) => colRef.add(element));
```